# Merging arrays without array_merge

Tags: php, arrays

Is this possible to merge multiple arrays in this way instead of `array_merge` function?

```
$defaults = array('a'=>'b');
$defaults .= array('c'=>'d');
print_r($defaults);?>
```

Comment: How about just testing it yourself?

Comment: `array_merge` is a native function. Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost, you need the `+` operator instead:

```
$defaults = array('a'=>'b');
$defaults += array('c'=>'d');
print_r($defaults);
```

Be aware, though, that it has a slightly different mode than `array_merge`, i.e. it does not override already defined keys/indexes.

Answer (score 4):

No, because the `.` and `.=` operators operate on strings only.

Operator `+` does work on arrays, and it has slightly different semantics than `array_merge`.

Array addition works like this:

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

`array_merge` works like this:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Comment: +1 Correct and most detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$defaults = array('a'=>'b');
$defaults += array('c'=>'d');
print_r($defaults);
```

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the different semantics.

Comment: Thats not merge. That array Union